# Azure VM migration - access denied

Tags: azure, authentication, ssh, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I followed this guide: [Copying a virtual machine from one Windows Azure subscription to another with PowerShell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2014/01/29/from-the-mvps-copying-a-virtual-machine-from-one-windows-azure-subscription-to-another-with-powershell.aspx) to move a Virtual Machine between two subscriptions.
It worked fine, I could log in to the machine (by SSH).
Then (in the destination subscription), I changed the VM size (from A2 to A0), and now I am getting the error:

> Access is denied

while logging by SSH. It is a *dev machine*, I am the only user (none changed my password).
I tried to put the size back to A2 without success.
Do you have any hints?

Comment: did you create your VM with certificate authetication or login/pass?

Comment: thank you for your comment, but no, I just have operating system (Ubuntu) login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have installed the Linux Agent, try resetting your credentials using preview portal:

Navigate to Azure Preview Portal >> Browse >> Virtual machines >> Select your VM >> All settings >> Password reset

[image]

You can also reset SSH config clicking "Reset Remote Access" in VM dashboard.

Comment: I took some times but it worked, thanks. Why changing the size of the VM "broke" the login / ssh ?